# How To Unit Test Blank DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-widget

I am trying to unit test a form which includes a date selector. It is saved in the model as `DateTimeField` and in the form uses a `DatePickerInput` widget.

This is the test:

```
def test_form_validation_for_blank_items(self):

        user = User.objects.create_superuser('username')
        self.client.force_login(user)

        form = PersonalInformationForm(data={
            'first_name': '',
            'surname': '',
            'gender': '',
            'dob': ''})

        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
        self.assertEqual(form.errors, {
            'first_name': ['This field is required.'],
            'surname': ['This field is required.'],
            'gender': ['This field is required.'],
        })
```

And the error that's thrown:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'year'
```

My other fields are fine, but I was wondering how to unit test a blank `DateTimeField` model with a `DatePickerInput` widget.

Thank you.

Comment: ```start_date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control  date''}),required=True)```  this will validated and show ```This field is required```  if the field is blank or null.

Comment: If you not allow blank then add ```required=True``` else ```required=False```.